# How can I change the color of JS variables without changing the color of their keys in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

I noticed that the `Default Dark+` theme has a different color for variables than the `Visual Studio Dark` theme.
`Dark+` has two different colors for the variable and member.

[image: Visual Studio Dark]
[image: Default Dark+]

I personally use the `Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast` theme and would like to override this setting.
But if I set the variable color i get the following result:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": {
    "variables": "#ff0000"
  }
}
```

[image: Material before]
[image: Material after]

How can I set the variable color to only affect it at declaration and reference like in `Default Dark+`?

TL;DR how can I set different colors for `test` and `key` on line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by using [the builtin TextMate scope inspector tool](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector).

Using it, you'll find that your `test` object has the semantic token type `variable.other.constant.object.js` and `variable`, and your `key` field has `variable.other.property.js`.

So for example, inside your `"[Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": {`:

```json
"textMateRules": [{
    "scope": "variable", // or variable.other.constant.object.js
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
    }
},{
    "scope": "variable.other.property.js",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#00FF00", // TODO
    }
}]
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you so much! 
Especially the TextMate tipp!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76010214/5418362) and TextMate scope inspector I came to the following solution.
Because I use TypeScript, I had to add the corresponding scopes for that too.

[image: final solution]

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": {
    "comments": "#058C42",
    "variables": "#ffe3fb",
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "variable.other.object.property.js",
          "variable.other.object.property.ts"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#e0c0db"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": [
          "variable.other.property.js",
          "variable.other.property.ts"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ea92db"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

I loved the base theme but it uses too much white.
This will improve visibility for me.